# Unescape HTML using JSP

Tags: java, jsp

If I have a Java class return escapeHTML format data. Then I want to unescape the information is a JSP script, is there such a way to do so?

only has escapeXml attributes.

Comment: Hi, do you mean unescaping HTML special characters? Can you elaborate on this, like show us what you've got and what you'd like to have?

Answer (score 2):

What about the classes in commons lang. Like [this](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4%28java.lang.String%29) for instance?